# Can I use write a regex to find and rearrange HTML tags, and if so how

Tags: html, regex

I have a simple HTML document for use in an ebook where I need to rearrange some italic HTML tags, but it’s much too long to do it all manually. For example, it can look like is this:

```
<p>some text <i>italic text</i> more text</p>

<p> some text <i>italic some more</p>

<p>even more italic on this line</p>

<p>italic</i> and some regular text</p>
```

And I want it to look like:

```
<p>some text <i>italic text</i> more text</p>

<p> some text <i>italic some more</i></p>

<p><i>even more italic on this line</i></p>

<p><i>italic</i> and some regular text</p>
```

So in a nutshell, if there is a paragraph that has an unclosed `<i>` tag, add a close tag before the `</p>` tag. Then keep adding italic tags to all subsequent paragraphs until it encounters a close tag, where it should add an `<i>` tag only to the beginning of that paragraph.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Parse it with an HTML parser, then serialize the result. That'll make it valid.

Answer (score 2):

As explained by  user1937198 and Ryan (and more detailed in the mentioned message [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)), regex is not the right tool here. In a browser's JavaScript engine, you have an HTML parser to your disposal which could help you. Check it in the console: when you enter the following statements,

```
var d = document.createElement("DIV");
d.innerHTML = "<p>some text <i>italic text</i> more text</p>\n"+
              "<p> some text <i>italic some more</p>\n"+
              "<p>even more italic on this line</p>\n"+
              "<p>italic</i> and some regular text</p>";
d.innerHTML;
```

you first parse your text and then output the parsed result. In the case at hand:

```
"<p>some text <i>italic text</i> more text</p>
<p> some text <i>italic some more</i></p><i>
<p>even more italic on this line</p>
</i><p><i>italic</i> and some regular text</p>"
```

So it's not *exactly* what you are looking for, but at least the `<i>`  tags are closed properly at ends of paragraphs. If `<i>` mode is continued after a paragraph's end, the new `<i>` will stand outside of the  `<p>` (which, strictly speaking, is more correct, since there may be text outside of the `<p>` elements which has to be italic then as well).